# are immersions of surfaces in $\mathbb R^3$ dense in all regular maps?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Let $u\in C^\infty(\Omega,\mathbf R^3)$ with $\Omega$ open set in $\mathbf R^2$. Can we find $u_k\in C^\infty(\Omega,\mathbf R^3)$ with $\mathrm{rank}(Du_k(x))=2$ for all $x\in\Omega$ such that $u_k \to u$ uniformly?

**added.** I actually have $\Omega$ bounded and $u\in C^\infty(\Omega)\cap C^0(\overline \Omega)$ with $u=0$ on $\partial \Omega$ and need to approximate uniformaly with functions $u_k$ with the same properties and full jacobian rank. Then I would like to apply Nash-Kuiper theorem to $u_k$ to obtain an isometric map approximating $u$.

Comment: Do you really want $u_k \to u$ uniformly, no conditions on derivatives? That's the wrong notion of convergence in $C^\infty(\Omega, \Bbb R^3)$. If I pretend instead that the domain is a compact surface (I'm frightened of mapping spaces with compact domain), I would expect the answer to be yes in the $C^0$ topology (yours) and false in the $C^1$ topology.

Comment: @MikeMiller : Do you have a counterexample if we assume stronger convergence ($C^k$ for some $k \ge 3$ or even $C^\infty$)?

Comment: I don't, unfortuantely! I'm not sure how one would be constructed. I would be excited to see one; my suspicions mostly come from Whitney's immersion theorem, where one only achieves density if the codomain is double the dimension of the domain.

Comment: I confirm $C^0$ convergence is what is needed. Seems to me some sort of transversality result.

Comment: @MikeMiller I have added some explanation in the question.